# $\mathring{M}$, $\overline{M}$ and $\partial M$ of $M = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \big[\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{k}{k+1} \big] \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How can one find out the interior $\mathring{M}$, the closure $\overline{M}$ and the boundary $\partial M$ of this set?

$$M = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \big[\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{k}{k+1} \big] \subset \mathbb{R}$$

I don't even know how to draw this region in the plane..

Comment: It is a subset of the real line…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction we have $[\frac{1}{k+1} , \frac{k}{k+1}] \subset (0,1)$. Thus $M\subset (0,1)$. Let $x\in (0,1)$. There exists  $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{k+1} \leq x \le 1 - \frac 1 {k+1} = \frac{k}{k+1}$. Therefore $x \in M$.

It follows that $M = (0,1)$. Thus $\overline{M} = [0,1]$, $\text{interior}(M) = (0,1)$, $\partial M = \{0,1\}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Rewrite each interval in the form
$$\biggl[\frac1{n+1},1-\frac 1{n+1}\biggr].$$